# How to call a so-called helper spelling to help reading a word?

Tags: vowels, syllables

Using words below as example:

```
team /tiːm/
head /ˈhed/
eat  /ēt/
```

The common syllable `ea` sound cannot always be pronounced consistently the same sound in English language. It differs per word. That's why there are e.g. `tiːm` , `ˈhed` or `ēt` coming along side in place to help us learn how to pronounce a word. In this question I call them `helper spelling` because I do not know how to call them.

How to call such a word, e.g. `tiːm`, `ˈhed`, `ēt`?

**To help express my question: `team` is a word and what is `tiːm`?**

How to call such a syllable,  e.g. `ə`, `i:`, `ē`?

**To help express my question: `ea` is a vowel sound and what is `iː`?**

I want to find a list of such syllables e.g. `ə`, `i:`, `ē` so that I know how to pronounce a new word which I've never heard before e.g.

```
  Write          Read
  ---------------------------
  consistent     kənˈsistənt
  confluence    ˈkänˌflo͞oəns
```

I do understand that Google Translate can help you read words but it cannot give  you knowledge related to above questions and I would to gain that knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

This is called *phonetic spelling* or *phonetic orthography*. The [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) (IPA) provides a standard set of symbols, and is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1. "Team" is a word, while "ti:m" is the phonetic spelling of the word.  Phonetic spellings have a unique symbol for each unique sound a human can make, and spell words based on their sounds irrespective of their original language.  [Wikipedia has a great article on all the different sounds and symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet).  There are also different phonetic alphabets.  Google, for example, uses the NOAD phonetic alphabet, [which can be seen here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English).
2. Without knowing where you acquired the phonetic spellings, I can't show you the pronunciation guide for that specific alphabet, but the second link above should help.  When you look up "team" on Google, it provides the phonetic spelling "/tēm/", which you can use the guide in my second link to understand how to sound out the word.